# Mysql: multiple choice list

Tags: mysql

I have a question about Mysql database tables creation,can someone tell me how to translate this to table and fields :

```
Subscription

         Price:
            Subscription => [select choices: PLN/EUR/USD/GBP]
            Activation => [select choices: PLN/EUR/USD/GBP]
        ....
```

This tree is a form to make subscription of a product,Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `price` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subscription` enum(`PLN`,`EUR`,`USD`,`GBP`),
    `activation` enum(`PLN`,`EUR`,`USD`,`GBP`)
);
```

Comment: and what about "price"?

Comment: I would store price as cents instead of Dollars
See update

Answer (score 1):

maybe  this is `ENUM` column type, see desc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html